# Best Way to Read Lisbox Array

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am using a sql query to retrieve data and write to a listbox. However, sometimes an item may have more than one value.

IE:

Data: "Patient Disclosure"
Value: "Encounter"

or

Data: "Patient Disclosure"
Value: "Order"

In the listbox, the line item will show only "Patient Disclosure" but I have the values written in the array. However, I don't want two of the same line item to appear. The "order" value should be the only one showing if it has multiple values. How can I do this?

```vb
While reader.Read()
    Dim Myitem As New List(Of myitems)
    Myitem.Add(New myitems with {.Description = reader(0), .Value = reader(2)})
    '               If reader(2) = "Order" Then
    '                   listBox1.Items.Add(Myitem.ToArray)
    '               Else
    '                   listBox1.Items.Add(reader(0))
    '               End If

    listBox1.Items.AddRange(Myitem.ToArray)
End While
```

Comment: since the source is a DB why not use a DataGridView which easily supports columns?

Comment: I don't want all of the columns available for the user. They should only see the "data" portion.

Comment: what does `MyItem` look like?  you might be able to just override the `ToString` function to return whatever you want to show, then just store myItem objects to the listbox (see below) (DGV can have hidden columns - many do)

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate duplicates with

```vb
listBox1.Items.AddRange(Myitem.Distinct().ToArray())
```

However, I am not sure what you are asking. I good thing to do is to create a class that holds your data, instead of working directly with data readers, as you have done already. Give it a more descriptive name than `myitems`. As developers we are constantly working with many kinds of "items".

```vb
Public Class Patient // Or whatever the items are supposed to represent.
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Value As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("Description = {0}, Value = {1}", Description, Value)
    End Function
End Class
```

If you then add `Patient` objects to a `ListBox`, the `ListBox` will automatically use `ToString` to display the items.

You can also override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in order to influence the way two objects are compared. The `Distinct` method will use these two methods in order to do its job. See: [Implementing the Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)